# A8:// protocol in URI Customized Schemes

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to have Notepad++ make links with the [A8://](https://support.authentic8.com/support/solutions/articles/16000026507-open-a-web-page-directly-in-silo) and A8s:// protocols clickable.

I added A8:// A8s:// a8:// and a8s:// into the URI customized schemes box under "Cloud & Link" tab of Preferences but Notepad++ isn't making any of the urls clickable. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I got the same behaviour, probably a bug! Have you asked [Notepad++ community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/)?